# paypal fee calculation

Tags: paypal

I am using PayPal Adaptive Payment and I want to know how PayPal calculates it's fee

I check the following link https://www.x.com/message/60352;jsessionid=54722E9CCAC2DE9E28CAA411F16AB457.node0#60352

It says

> PayPal charges 2.9% + .30 cents per transactions (unless your montly volume qualifies you for a lower rate).

Where as, following calculation doesn't work in my case

I have $24.49 product, and PayPal fees is 0.39 (which doesn't match with above thing)

anyone have idea how it gets calculated?

```
Edited: 
These are IPN values for $100 transaction :: [mc_fee]=>0.42 [mc_gross]=>100.00
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0.39 seems too low. Check this http://www.rolbe.com/paypal.htm out.

Comment: Yes. I realized that. Even 1.9% + .30 is more than 0.39

Comment: Old post, but it's a dead link.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a PayPal fee calculator that take into account all the parameters of the transaction like your country and currency and whether it is a domestic transaction.

Here is a link to the calculator that I use: http://www.convertforfree.com/paypal-fee-calculator/